# Como retornar um JSON em PHP?

Tags: php, angularjs

Tenho isso:

```
$insereUsuario=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (idUsuario, idCep, tipoUsuario, nome, usuario, email, senha) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$insereUsuario->bindValue(1, NULL); 
$insereUsuario->bindValue(2, $idCep); 
$insereUsuario->bindValue(3, $tipoUsuario); 
$insereUsuario->bindValue(4, $nome);
$insereUsuario->bindValue(5, $usuario);
$insereUsuario->bindValue(6, $email);
$insereUsuario->bindValue(7, $senha);
$insereUsuario->execute();

$idUsuario = $pdo->lastInsertId();

//$data = array();

$result = array(
   'email' => $email,
   'nome' => $nome,
   'usuario' => $usuario,
   'idUsuario' => $idUsuario,
   'tipoUsuario' => $tipoUsuario
  );

//$data[] = $result;
print_r($result);
```

Estou tetando pegar esse object JSON no angular, e no console aparece isso:
"Array\n(\n    [email] => olaflavia@hotmail.com\n    [nome] => Fl�via Schneider\n    [usuario] => Fl�via\n    [idUsuario] => 33\n    [tipoUsuario] => C\n)\n"

Como corrigir isso?
Valeu.

Comment: $result = array( 'email' => $email, 'nome' => $nome, 'usuario' => $usuario, 'idUsuario' => $idUsuario, 'tipoUsuario' => $tipoUsuario ); echo json_encode($result);

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa adicionar o header para que o navegador reconheça o formato, em seguida serializar o objeto em json:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser que rode:

```
$result['email'] = '$email';
$result['nome'] = '$nome';
echo json_encode($result);
```